# Pushwoosh sdk doesn't work on Nativescript ios app

Tags: ios, typescript, nativescript, pushwoosh

I'm trying to use PushWoosh SDK (http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/native-ios-sdk) in my Nativescript (angular with typescript) project.
for this reason i did the following:

1. Extended UIApplicationDelegate (code below)
2. Added nativescript-entitlments plugin. with aps-environment (tried both development and production values).
3. Added the required props to in info.plist (including even Pushwoosh_APPID_dev), and added remote-notification to UIBackgroundModes
4. Created and uploaded my certificates to two different pushwoosh apps (one for dev, one for prod). and have my AppId allow push notification
5. Created and installed a pushwoosh plugin. which includes a podfile. (I even tried adding 'use_frameworks!' to that podfile.
6. I tried running through local "tns run ios" and also through TestFlight

Results of running on a device:

1. The delegate runs, the SDK methods are being called Without errors. The app asks me to allow push notifications when i open it.
2. In Pushwoosh portal I can see change in my IOS device count, but none of the devices are "Push enabled" (what does it mean?)
3. In Pushwoosh statistics I can see "app open" events from IOS.
4. application.currentUserNotificationSettings seems OK
5. application.registeredForRemoteNotifications returns True.
6. PushWoosh static method 'PushNotificationManager.getRemoteNotificationStatus' returns everything with value 1 (enabled, sound, etc).
7. In debug mode i can see that Pushwoosh reads AppCode (and name and hwid) properties well.
8. **when I run it on a device i see no Pushwoosh logging in the console**. even though i used Pushwoosh_LOG_LEVEL VERBOSE in info.plist.
   but if i run it on the emulator i can see Pushwoosh log events and outgoing requests. **WHY?** Logs are important, what is the different between the emulator and a device? I tried many things to solve this. **What can be done?**

It seems like everything is fine, but the registration callbacks are not called, and if i try to call "getPushToken" in "applicationDidBecomeActive" it is null, and as i said - no "push enabled" devices in Pushwoosh portal.

AppDelegate.ios.ts:

```
import * as application from "application";
import "@zapsod/ns-pushwoosh" // My PW Plugin
import { ios } from "application";
import {platformCommon} from "./platform-common"

declare var PushNotificationManager;
declare var PushNotificationDelegate;
declare interface PushNotificationDelegate{

onPushAccepted(pushManager, withNotification, onStart);

didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken(deviceToken);

didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError(error);

didReceiveRemoteNotification(userInfo, completionHandler);
}
var pushManager =PushNotificationManager.pushManager();

//var PushNotificationManager = <any>pw.PushNotificationManager;

export class MyDelegate extends UIResponder implements 
UIApplicationDelegate, PushNotificationDelegate{
public static ObjCProtocols = [UIApplicationDelegate, 
PushNotificationDelegate];

applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(application: UIApplication, 
launchOptions): boolean {
    console.profile();
    console.log("applicationWillFinishLaunchingWithOptions: ", this)
    pushManager.delegate = this;
    UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = 
    pushManager.notificationCenterDelegate;
    pushManager.sendAppOpen();
    console.log(application.currentUserNotificationSettings);
    pushManager.registerForPushNotifications();

    return true;
}

applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication): void {
    console.log("applicationDidBecomeActive:  " + application)

    console.log("is registered", 
application.registeredForRemoteNotifications)
}

onPushAccepted(pushManager, withNotification, onStart){
    console.log("pushaccepted", withNotification)
}

didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken(deviceToken) {
    console.info("registered for pushed token ", platformCommon)
    platformCommon.pushToken = deviceToken;
    pushManager.handlePushRegistration(deviceToken);
}

didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError(error){
    console.error("failed to register push ", error)
    pushManager.handlePushRegistrationFailure(error)
}

didReceiveRemoteNotification(userInfo, completionHandler){
    pushManager.handlePushReceived(userInfo);
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
}
}
application.ios.delegate = MyDelegate;
```

Comment: Couldn't solve it.. i let it go and used other framework